# mean of population with repeated samples of varying size - how to apply CLT?

Tags: sample-size, central-limit-theorem

I have a population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
I draw a sample with $n_i$ number of i.i.d random observations from population. I compute the mean for this sample as $mean_i$. I then repeat this experiment k times drawing samples of different sizes, $n_i$, every time.

Questions:
1) will the $mean_i$ form a normal distribution? (edit: distribution of means across i )
2) What would be the std deviation of such a distribution? It cannot be $\sigma/\sqrt n$ as the n is changing for every sample.
3) If i now take average of all these means, can i construct confidence interval around that measurement for original population mean?

Answer (score 2):

> Questions: 1) will the mean(i) still form a normal distribution?

i) The $i^\text{th}$ mean won't be normal (the CLT isn't about samples of size $n_i$), though in very large samples a standardized mean may be close to normally distributed.

ii) The distribution of means across $i$ won't be normal in general even as sample sizes go to infinity. (I expect this is what you were trying to ask about)

> 2) What should be the std deviation of such a distribution?

This is unclear. Are you asking about the distribution of the sample means?

It would be some (scale) [mixture distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures), so basic results about the moments - and from that, the variance - of finite mixtures should hold.

> 3) If i now take average of all these means, can i construct confidence interval around that measurement for original population mean?

Possibly. One example approach: as the number of means goes to infinity, if some conditions hold* you could perhaps make use of an argument relating to the Lyapunov or Lindeberg versions of CLT along with Slutsky's theorem**. There are some other things that might be done.

* see those versions of the CLT; for example, you'll essentially need that none of the variances "dominate" the sum of the variances.

** but again, note that they're actually about what happens in the limit, not at a finite sample size.

---

Of course, if you know the $n_i$'s and the $\bar{x}_i$'s you can form the unweighted average, and if you have the sample standard deviations, you should also be able to calculate the [overall standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Sample-based_statistics) as if you had all the data... and you can apply a more "common" approach then.

Comment: Thanks very much again. You have answered all the questions that i had asked. As an extension, can i ask what happens if n(i)= n for all the samples. Am i correct to assume that CLT will hold in that case and answers to questions would be: questions 1) distribution of means from all i samples would be normal question 2) std deviation of sample means would be sigma/sqrt(n) question 3) I am still not sure here

Comment: 1) No, for the reasons I already gave under "i)" in my answer.  2) Yes, if I understand correctly what you're asking. 3) You could, probably in the way you intend, but you could also do what I suggested in my answer for the unequal sample sizes case (calculate the mean and s.d. for the combined sample from the means, s.d.'s and sample sizes for each group).

Comment: Thanks a lot. question 1) Its (ii) that i was asking and i believe answer is yes if sample size every time is same. question 3) when sample size is same every time,n, for a total of k number of samples (considering k and n as large and population variance to be known ), does this hold ?$$\frac{\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}mean_i - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{k}}} \sim N(0,1)$$

Comment: On thinking more, what i wrote above in question (3) extension does hold true. Its equivalent to drawing one sample of $n*k$ size. This is what Glen_b has been alluding to as well i guess.

Comment: Your distribution is only the case if the samples are from a normal distributions, or $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ (though I'm reading $\sim$ as "is distributed as", so if you mean something else, maybe it's true). You're correct about what I was alluding to.

Comment: yes, $\lim_{n,k\to \infty}$